# Polynomial quotient rings

Tags: polynomials, quotient-spaces

I have a quotient ring $R=\Bbb Z[t]/(1-t)^3$.

It is asked to show that $\overline{2t^3-2}=\overline{6t^2-6t}$ and $\overline{1-4t^3}=\overline{4t-6t^2-t^4}$.

I feel like I am missing some important idea, this is how I proceeded.

$(1-t)^3=(1-3t+3t^2-t^3)$ is the neutral element here, this should be an ideal of $R$.

so I am tempted to write $\overline{2t^3-2}=\overline{2t^3-2+2*(1-3t+3t^2-t^3)}=\overline{6t^2-6t+1}$ which produces the wrong result.

I fail to see where I went wrong.

$\Bbb Z[t]=\{a+bt|a,b\in\Bbb Z\}$ so I am thinking of the equivalent classes in $R=\Bbb Z[t]/(1-t)^3$ as the residue classes if I divided by $(1-t)^3$.

Is it because I am thinking of $(1-t)^3=(1-3t+3t^2-t^3)$ as $0$, but thinking of it as identity element makes no sense for me.

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to show those things?

Comment: It was asked so in the book, but I believe first one to be a typo now. It should say $\overline{2(t^3-1)}$ most likely.

Comment: I've edited your question to reflect the typo, and updated my answer as well.

Comment: @Rob You can do this very easily using derivatives - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is true, writing

$$(t-1)^3=0\mod (t-1)^3\iff t^3-3t^2+3t-1=0\mod (t-1)^3$$
$$\iff 3t^2-3t=t^3-1\mod (t-1)^3$$

But then we see that $2(3t^2-3t)=6t^2-6t= 2(t^3-1)=2t^2-2\mod (t-1)^3$.

For the other one, use $a=b\mod I\iff a-b\in I$, so that

$$(1-4t^3)-(4t-6t^2-t^3)=1-4t+6t^2-3t^3$$

however, for this to be $=0\mod (t-1)^3$ we need $3t^3-6t^2+4t-1=p(t)(t-1)^3$. But then necessarily $\deg p(t)=0$ and indeed $p(t)=3$ by considering just the first coefficient, again impossible.

Comment: Thank you! I miswrote the second one instead of $t^4$ I had written $t^3$, which i corrected now and it comes out correct and the first one must be a mistake in the book. I should have trusted my gut on this and not spent so much time dwelling on it. Thank you so much for your help, writing it out with mod makes it much more intuitive to read.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\ \ &&g(t)\equiv h(t)\ \ {\rm in}\ \ \Bbb Z[t]\ {\rm mod}\ (t\!-\!1)^3\\
\iff && (t\!-\!1)^3\!\mid g(t)\!-\!h(t) =: f(t)\ \ {\rm in}\ \ \Bbb Z[t]\\
\iff && 0 = f(1) = f'(1) = f''(1)\ \  \text{by Taylor series expansion at}\,\ t = 1
\end{eqnarray}$

**Example** $ $ your $\,f = 2t^3\!-\!6t^2\!+6t\!-\!2,\ f'\! = 6t^2\!-\!12t\!+\!6,\ f''\! = 12t\!-\!2\ $ so we easily compute that $\, f(1) = f'(1)=f''(1) = $ coefficient sum $= 0\,$ for all three polynomials.